# Terminology on comparison of homotopy types

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology, homotopy-theory

I'm asked to compare the homotopy type of two topological spaces, and I'm not sure what words to use.

For example, given $S^1$ and $S^1\lor S^1$, I know that the fundamental group of $S^1$ is a proper subgroup of the fundamental group $S^1\lor S^1$. I would like to say something like "The homotopy type of $S^1$ is smaller than the homotopy type of $S^1\lor S^1$".

Furthermore, I wouldn't like to rely on the subgroup relation, since any free group has as subgroup any other free group. In the previous example I could use the fact that the rank of $\mathbb{Z}$ is strictly smaller than the rank of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$.

**Question:** Is there any common terminology for the comparison of homotopy types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really make much sense in general to compare homotopy types in more than the most basic language. For example, how do the homotopy types of $S^1$ and $S^\infty$ compare? Since $S^1$ includes into $S^\infty$, you might be tempted to say that $S^1$ is 'smaller' than $S^\infty$. But $S^\infty$ is weakly contractible, so contains a lot less homotopic information than even $S^1$. These spaces are simply homotopically *different*.

It does make sense, however, to say that a space $A$ is a retract, or deformation of another space $X$ (which is the case for your example). This is really the only case that you might be tempted to say that $A$ is 'smaller' than $X$, since all the homotopy and homology groups of $A$ appear as summands of those of $X$. Hence $X$ contains all the basic homotopic information of $A$, as well as possibly more. You still need to take care, though, since $A$ and $X$ may actually be homotopy equivalent.

Comment: I would add that if someone asks you to "compare" two homotopy types, that almost certainly just means to determine whether they are the same or not.

Comment: The paper "Modelling and computing homotopy types: I" available from https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019357717300460 gives a more complex view of homotopy types.